# How do I copy files with curly brace expansion in the path?

Tags: linux

I have a file that is the same name (different data) and is located in multiple directories.

An example:

```
/path/to/this/dir1/data.csv
/path/to/this/dir2/data.csv
/path/to/this/dir3/data.csv
/path/to/this/dir4/data.csv
```

I want to copy these files (with their respective folder immediately above it) to a new location.

I tried something like this (dir1, dir2, dir3, dir4 are already made):

```
cp -rf /path/to/this/{dir1,dir2,dir3,di4}/data.csv ./{dir1,dir2,dir3,dir4}/.
```

This of course doesn't work, but I am not sure how to properly do it in one line (which would be preferred, but if a script needs to be written is not a big deal).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `cp` supports the `--parents` option, you can use

```
cd /path/to/this
cp --parents dir{1..4}/data.csv /path/to/target/
```

The `for` loop should also work:

```
for data in /path/to/this/dir{1..4}/data.csv ; do
    cp $data ${data#path/to/this/}
done
```

Or, use `find` (no brace expansion ivolved):

```
cd /path/to/this
find -path './dir[1234]' -exec cp {}/data.csv /path/to/target/{} \;
```